# How to stop activity when my application icon is clicked again

Tags: android, android-activity

[image: When i click training icon it show the button named Home]

When i click training icon it show the button named Home.

[image]

When i click home button it shows the home screen as below.

[image]

My application is currently running right, I want to close the application and have to show the home screen when i click the app icon(training).How could i do this..?

[image]

Actually i have a button in my layout and i'm showing the home screen with the following code when the button is pressed.

```
Intent startMain = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
startMain.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
startMain.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(startMain);
```

It shows the home screen and my service in background has started.
I want to stop all the action from my app to be stopped when i click launcher icon.
My question is how can i stop the activity when my application icon is clicked again.

Sorry for poor english..!

Answer (score 0):

If you application consists only of an Activity then it is already stopped when the user re-clicks the launcher icon (since he had to exit the app).
We need more info if that's not your scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Put `finish();` on the method `onResume()`.

Of course, if you need to do something else, just put your code before the `finish();`.

It should do.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can check if your service is running, or more dirty with a static int counter. Let the counter increment in your `onCreate()`. Now you can check for the second start of your apk

Answer (score 0):

Use it in your activity. When you exit from your app it will stop the action as well as destroy the app. And it will launch new activity when you click your app icon again.

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Actually i want to kill the application when i click the icon second time.It doesn't work.